# Unique constraint on a pair of fields, bidirectional

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Take this model for example

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together('user1', 'user2')
```

The [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together) constraint will only work in one direction. The same relationship can be represented in 2 different ways:

user1 = Foo

user2 = Bar

AND

user1 = Bar

user2 = Foo

Is it possible to use `unique_together` to enforce a bidirectional constraint at the database level?

**Edit**: If not, how can this constraint be enforced?

Comment: Based on django rules, it is not possible to enforce a bidirectional constraint for the above mentioned example as both are different.

Comment: Thanks Vijesh. Any idea how this can be enforced?

Comment: [Django custom unique together constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15219938/1995738)

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the model's save() method to enforce the most sophisticated constraints you can think of.